# Can not insert an image in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
sampledb=# insert into books(book_pic) values(pg_read_file('C/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/ADC.jpeg')::bytea);
ERROR:  could not open file "C/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/ADC.jpeg" for reading: No such file or directory
sampledb=#
```

Comment: That should be `C:/...` not `C/...`

Comment: That's a pretty clear problem: No such file or directory

Comment: Then how can i insert an image in Postgresql?

Comment: ERROR:  could not open file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/ADC.jpeg" for reading: No such file or directory
sampledb=#

Comment: the error does NOT contain a `:` ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Besides, that function reads a `text` and won't work with binary data. You'll have to write some client code to do that.

Comment: use `pg_read_binary_file()` to get bytea result with no encoding check instead of `pg_read_file() :: bytea`

Comment: sampledb=# insert into books(book_pic) values(pg_read_binary_file('C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/ADC.jpeg'));
ERROR:  could not open file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/ADC.jpeg" for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: Check the pg documentation, 'Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed, unless the user is a superuser or is granted the role pg_read_server_files'

Comment: [File access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE)

Comment: sampledb=# insert into books(book_pic) values(bytea('C:/Users/mparu/OneDrive/Desktop/ADC.jpeg'));
INSERT 0 1
sampledb=#
Thanks guys for your help